# He actualizado Android Studio y ahora veo errores que antes no

Tags: android, android-studio

Pues eso, funcionaba todo perfecto..he actualizado el Android Studio y ahora no funciona.

Veo errores en build, Run tasks.. y no tengo ni pajorera idea de que se trata ni como solucionarlo

Esta es una imagen de lo que veo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien veo que en alguno de mis Activitys me sale en rojo la "R", aquí:

```
import static com.android.rodry.chistes.R.id.activity_showchistes;
```

aqui:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_showchistes);
```

y aqui:

```
textView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.BrackgroundChistes));
```

También veo unos Warnings en la pestaña Sync:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mis dependencias de build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Limpia el proyecto y hazle un rebuild. A veces sólo necesita eso.

Comment: Y cómo se limpia el proyecto y se hace un rebuild ? Perdona pero llevo 3 días empezando con Android desde 0 y no me entero de nada

Answer (score 2):

Dirigete a

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ve a [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y Cambiar **compile**  por **implementation**

y presiona[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se que es eso porque en tu imagen claramente se ve compile en naranja con rayas lo cual significa deprecated

ademas de que lo indica 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si sigue marcando error remplaza lo que indica tu imagen
TestCompile por Testimplementation etc

Comment: Lo he hecho y me sigue pasando lo mismo, anda mas darle a Sync Now me aparece lo que he puesto en la primera imagen

Comment: Tambien cambia 
testCompile por testImplementation

androidTestCompile por androidTestImplementation

Comment: Hecho y aun aparece un warning: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (24.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.1.

Comment: a ver si puedes unirte al chat del otro comentario...

Answer (score 2):

Primeramente es importante cambiar en tu build.grade el uso de

- `compile` por `implementation`
- `testCompile` por `testImplementation`
- `androidTestCompile` por `androidTestImplementation`

ya que su uso es obsoleto para definir dependencias, ya que también se actualizó la version de `Gradle` que usa `Android Studio`, esto lo debes cambiar dentro del bloque `dependencies` , ejemplo :

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

ya que es el problema principal indicado en la consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al realizar ester cambio simplemente sincroniza nuevamente el archivo build.gradle con tu proyecto  mediante la opción "Sync Now":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*** importante actualizar tu `Android SDK Build Tools` a la versión `28.0.3` como minimo ya que es la version minima soportada por `Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.1`.**

Cambia:

```
buildToolsVersion '24.0.2'
```

a :

```
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
```

Comment: Hehco, me sigue apareciendo este mensaje: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (24.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.1.

Comment: importante actualizar tu Android SDK Build Tools a 28.0.3 ! Es la minima que permite Android Studio en su actualización @Rodrypaladin

Comment: Dirijete a compileSdkVersion y coloca 28 y en target targetSdkVersion igual 28

Comment: Hecho, le doy a Try Again sync pero nada, me dice otra vez try again

Comment: @Darkeniel No es  necesario cambiar  compileSdkVersion y targetSdkVersion a 28, eso incluso podria provocar problemas.

Comment: importante actualizar tu Android SDK Build Tools a la versión 20.0.3 como minimo ya que es la version minima soportada por Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.1. 

Vale pero como la actualizo ? Hay algo desde el propio Android Studio, o tengo que ir a alguna web específica

Comment: @Rodrypaladin eso se debe a que cambiaste el  compileSdkVersion y targetSdkVersion  es asi? Si lo realizaste da alt+enter sobre esa linea para que te sugiera la version apropiada. Agrega tu build.gradle con el cambio a "implementation"

Comment: Supuestamente ya tengo Android SDK Tools 26.1.1, o eso me dicen los settings

Comment: @Jorgesys Puse una imagen nueva, por si puedes echarle un ojo, estoy desesperado, no paro de hacer cosas que sugiere Android Studio y estoy liandolo más, No se si desinstalando Android Studio y volviendolo a instalar se solucionaría, pero no quiero perder el proyecto

Comment: @Rodrypaladin tu problema es básicamente configuración, cambia la versión de buildToolsVersion en tu build.gradle, revisa la actualización de mi respuesta.

Comment: @Jorgesys Cambié lo que dijiste, intenté sincronizar y lo mismo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85628/discussion-between-rodrypaladin-and-jorgesys).